# ng-blur the model's updated value is not avaiable in event

Tags: angularjs

I am using the ng-model-options to prevent my text input's model from being updated until the focus is lost.  That part all works.  However, I need to handle the event after the text input loses focus and the model is updated. In that event I need access to the NEW model's updated value, not the old one.

I am trying to use the ng-blur event, however, inside my handler the value is the old value, not the new value entered.  Am I doing something wrong or is there a better way to get the newly committed model value after the text input loses focus?

```
<input type="text"
ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur', debounce:0 }"
ng-model="vm.myModel.amount"
ng-blur="vm.handleBlurEvent(vm.myModel.amount)" />


vm.handleBlurEvent = function(item)
{
            //alert(item.amount); //Old amount - not new amount entered
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for those suggestions.  I actually managed to get this to work by adding 1 option to the updateOn property of ng-model-options.  By adding in 'default' everything worked!

ng-model-options = "{updateOn: 'default blur}" was the trick.

```
<input type="text"
ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'default blur' }"
ng-model="vm.myModel.amount"
ng-blur="vm.handleBlurEvent(vm.myModel.amount)" />


vm.handleBlurEvent = function(item)
{
            //alert(item.amount); //new shows the NEW amount :-)
}
```

Comment: here's a plunkr I created to demonstrate - try it without the default keyword and it won't work - with it it will...http://plnkr.co/edit/0cIELjdUgic5ffo77Ef4?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for the plunkr, really helped to debug this!
Your solution is a little flawed though, adding 'default' says to the subsystem "use the default updateOn action".
What I think we want is to delay the update to the model until the blur event, so leave updateOn: 'blur' and use ng-change to execute the function instead of ng-blur

Answer (score 16):

This is reworked from previous response by [user1750537](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1750537/user1750537), delay the model update until control blur and then process the change once, no de-bounce required and the model value will be set before your change logic as expected.

```
<input type="text"
ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }"
ng-model="vm.myModel.amount"
ng-change="vm.handleChangeEvent(vm.myModel.amount)" />

vm.handleChangeEvent = function(item)
{
   alert(item.amount); //new shows the NEW amount :-)
}
```

Comment: Thanks Chris - that makes sense and is a cleaner implementation :-)

Answer (score 4):

I don't have better luck with debounce yet

but to make your things working here is the code

```
<form name="amountForm" >
     <input type="text" name="amount"
     ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur', debounce:0 }"
     ng-model="vm.myModel.amount"
     ng-blur="vm.handleBlurEvent()" />
</form>

vm.handleBlurEvent = function()
{
     alert($scope.amountForm.amount.$viewValue);
}
```

enjoy...

Answer (score 1):

Old question but I've found another way to read this value, I couldn't remove debounce with delay and what worked for me was using timeout:

```
  $timeout(function(){
    var amount = this.formName.amount.value;
  });
```

I think this = ngModelController in above code.

Comment: This should be considered an anti-pattern. It leads to 'timeout hell', where it becomes impossible to easily reason about the order of events in your code. Eventually, users of a component adopting this anti-pattern will be forced to use $timeout's. There begins the journey to $timeout hell.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a watch?

You can do your logic once the model is updated like this:

```
 $scope.$watch('vm.myModel.amount', function (newVal, oldVal) {
        if (newVal != oldVal) {
         //do your logic here.
        }
    }, true);
```